# Changing color scheme of calendar icons?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color, icon, layers

Here's the image I'm working with:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically change all the images to using a color scheme close to #489fdc. I've tried making changes in Paint.NET and Photoshop, but haven't had any luck. Does anyone have experience with doing this?

I only have the .png version and not a .psd - otherwise this would of course be easy :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no photoshop and I can't give a proper answer with the result, but after a few search with google images I've found [here](http://www.graphicsfuel.com/2012/02/calendar-icon-psd/) the original psd file.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is tagged as [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design):

Although your purpose for these calendar images is not clear, in order to create this in the most dynamic way, I'd recommend using HTML's little know `<time>` element (which is [supported back to IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)) and CSS as opposed to creating a bunch of variation images because it's much easier to update.

Here's a basic structure you could use (pulled from Craig Buckler's [article on the subject](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-calendar-icon-html5-css3/)), you could just replace the text with what you need.

```
<time datetime="2014-09-20" class="icon"> 
  <em>Saturday</em>
  <strong>September</strong>
  <span>20</span>
</time>
```

With some added styling, you can create something [quite similar](http://jsfiddle.net/p0z54tsf/1/) to what you're wanting. You could even create the rings on top by using pseudo elements.

If you use a preprocessor like SCSS, you could make changing the color scheme (even with gradients) could be as simple as changing one variable.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way in photoshop would be to open the image in photoshop, go to image/adjustments/hue&saturation, select colorize and then tune the Hue and Saturation sliders. Because you are using a png, you might have to clip out the parts you do not want to be effected and leave those parts a layer above the copy of the image with the parts you need to effect with color.